# How can I exclude the password and remember token column in output

Tags: php, laravel, left-join

My profile controller looks like this

```
public function notifications(){
    $notifs=DB::table('notifications')
                                ->leftJoin('users','users.id','notifications.user_logged')
                                ->where('user_hero',Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('status',1)
                                ->orderBy('notifications.created_at','disc')
                                ->get();
                                dd($notifs);
}
```

This is how my output looks like:
[image: This is how my output looks like]

Comment: If you use a `Model` for `Notification`, you can assign `password` to the `protected $hidden = []` setting, and it should hide automatically. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Select the fields that will be used:

```
public function notifications(){
    $notifs=DB::table('notifications')
        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','notifications.user_logged')
        ->where('user_hero',Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('status',1)
        ->orderBy('notifications.created_at','disc')
        ->select(['users.id', 'users.email', 'notifications.note' ...])
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the select method `select('id','name','email')` to select the needed columns

Your method should look like this:

```
public function notifications(){
    $notifs=DB::table('notifications')
        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','notifications.user_logged')
        ->where('user_hero',Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('status',1)
        ->orderBy('notifications.created_at','disc')
        ->select('users.id', 'users.email')
        ->get();
}
```

check this answer on laracast:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-exclude-a-specific-column-from-query-when-using-query-builder